# Javascript Create Json

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm trying to create and post a json message in the following format:

```
var listObjects = [];

$.each(results, function(index, value){

var item = new Object();
item.title = value.Title;
item.code = value.Code;

listObjects.push(item);

});

var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(listObjects);
```

basically this will create my json like this:

```
[{"title":"Product 1","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 2","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 3","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 4","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 5","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 11","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 12","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 13","code":123456789012}]
```

how can I do it so that if I want to add some metadata to my json that will not repeat for each item but just at the top ... something like this:

```
category: x
type:   y
...
   items:
         title: .....
         code: ......
```

so basically the category and type will define the whole items in the json but are not repeated for each item ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I do it so that if I want to add some metadata to my json that will not repeat for each item but just at the top

Use an object as a wrapper with the meta data and the `items` array:

```
var jsonResult = JSON.stringify({
    category: x,
    type:     y,
    items:    listObjects
});
```

I'm assuming there that `x` and `y` are variables; if they're meant to be literals, put them in quotes.

---

Side note: In JavaScript, there's no reason to use `new Object`. Just use `{}`, which does the same thing. You can also put property initializers within it, rather than assigning to properties afterward. Here's your `$.each` with those changes (and indentation):

```
$.each(results, function(index, value){

    var item = {
        title: value.Title,
        code: value.Code
    };

    listObjects.push(item);

});
```

You can, of course, combine those:

```
$.each(results, function(index, value){

    listObjects.push({
        title: value.Title,
        code: value.Code
    });

});
```

---

Last but not least: What you're doing with `$.each` is exactly what [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is for:

```
var listObjects = $.map(results, function(index, value){
    return {
        title: value.Title,
        code: value.Code
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a object

```
var data={};
// your header
var header={category: x,type: y};
//your jsonresult
var jsonResult= [{"title":"Product 1","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 2","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 3","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 4","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 5","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 11","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 12","code":123456789012},
{"title":"Product 13","code":123456789012}]

data.heade=header;
data.result=jsonResult;

your data should be {header:{category: x,type: y},
jsonResult:[{"title":"Product 1","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 2","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 3","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 4","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 5","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 11","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 12","code":123456789012},
    {"title":"Product 13","code":123456789012}]
}
```